# htaccess QUERY_STRING urldecode

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, query-string

I have a problem concerning .htaccess and QUERY_STRING.

I try redirecting an URL with my htaccess that looks like this:

```
http://mydomain.tld/out/http%3A%2F%2Fotherdomain.tld%3Fparam%3D0
```

to

```
http://otherdomain.tld?param=0
```

I use RewriteCond and RewriteRule with the REQUEST_URI to redirect the url and everything works fine since REQUEST_URI is urldecoded by default in the htaccess.

However, when I email the link to Hotmail, Hotmail urldecodes the slashes and the question mark. The result looks like this:

```
http://mydomain.tld/out/http%3A//Fotherdomain.tld?param%3D0
```

So htaccess takes the link and tries to redirect it but due to the question mark the htaccess "thinks" everything behind the question mark is a QUERY_STRING.

The problem: apache2 doesn't urldecode the QUERY_STRING. So what happens is that htaccess redirects to

```
http://otherdomain.tld?param%3D0
```

which will fail.

So my question is:

**How can I tell htaccess to either urldecode the QUERY_STRING or use the full requested url (either urlendcoded or urldecoded) including the part after the question mark**

Thanks in advance!

Cheers

Comment: I also have a similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464298/rewrite-and-url-decoding
I also could not get an answer. Have you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

You need not add `[QSA]` to your rewrite rule to force htaccess to encode query string too.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html