# rewrite and url decoding

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, decode

It seems a site is linking to mine in a bad way.
From google webmaster tools I see some 404 errors

```
domain.com/file.php?id=1 (404) Not found    (Date)
```

This url works ok but because of browser page decoding, the real (404) url is

```
domain.com/file.php%3Fid%3D1 (this is what my browser displays in the url input when I click on google url)
```

My first try was

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\%3F(.*)$ $1?$2 [R=301, L]
```

to change `%3F` to '`?`' but it does not work. It is confusing what is real and what is en/decoded.

Thanks

Comment: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id\%3D(.+)`  `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?id=%1 [R=301,L]` does change %3D by '=' for file.php?id%3D1.

Comment: Oh, You tried %3F already.. hmm. There might be something else afoot.

Comment: Any help please?  From Google Webmaster tools I still am getting this kind of errors. Referrers are third pages linking to mines. I cannot redirect them in any way.

Comment: At this time GWT summary displays the encoded url: domain.com/file.php%3Fid%3D1 not the decode one as it did in the past

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not an elegant solution, but after months, it is the only way I found.

Regular case

```
domain.tld/dir/file.php?id=UID&qty=NUM&...   (from old site structure)
```

is rewritten as

```
domain.tld/newfile.php?id=UID&qty=NUM&... [R=301,L]
```

So, for requests like

```
domain.tld/dir/file.php%3Fid%3DUID%26qty=NUM%26...   (from old site structure)
```

I perform

```
RewriteRule ^dir/file\.php(.*)$ script.php?qs=$1 [R,L]
```

This MUST be AFTER all directives that involves dir/file.php

Then I can handle the query string $_GET['qs'] in script.php

It may not apply to other situations that would enter into a loop or undesired results.

Comment: @craniumonempty Those not decoded urls generate a 404 error, so 404.php is displayed to the user. I can decode REQUEST_URI and forward him to the decoded url from this file (if encoded and decoded versions differ). Is this a good practice? Web spiders will first get a 404 header, and then?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, try this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*\%3F.*)\%26([^%]*)(\%3D)?(.*)$ $1&$2=$4 [N]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\%3F([^%]*)(\%3D)?(.*)$ $1?$2=$4 [R=301,L]
```

EDIT: I see you already tested for %3F... if that didn`t work, then something else might be up.

Comment: No, it didn't work.  I cannot realize what to do. No other similar rules are written that would affect http behavior.

Answer (score 0):

use [NE] flag in your RewriteRule