# htaccess redirect to url parameter

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Is it possible to redirect with htaccess, from

```
http://example.com/redirect.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fanother.com%2Fsmiley.gif
```

to url parameter,

```
http://another.com/smiley.gif
```

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /redirect\.php\?url=.+([^/]+\.gif)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://another.com/%1? [NE,L,R]
```

This will redirect **/redirect.php?url=foobar/foobar.gif** to **http://another.com/foobar.gif** .

Comment: Thanks @starkeen. But, actually my question is similar with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246497/htaccess-query-string-urldecode. it have not solved my problem.

Comment: @kun what do you mean by "it hasnt solved my problem"? Does it redirect the url to wrong destination or what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: @starken the parameter "url=" is contain url, not path as your sample. and it is encoded, and also not only another.com. so, with your script, it redirect to `http://another.com/http%3A%2F%2Fanother.com%2Fsmiley.gif`. what i want is redirect to `http://another.com/smiley.gif` or `http://bnother.com/image.jpg`

Comment: @Kun I have added a NE no escape flag to the rule. please try the updated rule and let me know how it works.